# Inverse of Grassmann variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, grassmannian, hypercomplex-numbers

Let $\theta$ be a Grassmann variable. I know that $1/\theta$ is not defined but $\frac{1}{1-\theta}=1+\theta$. My question is simple: is $\frac{1}{\bar{\theta}\theta}$ defined and if so how? My guess is that since $\bar{\theta}\theta$ is a commuting number then the inverse should exist but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by $\bar{\theta}$?

Comment: Is $\theta$ a generator or just some variable? This symbol is usually used for generators, which are constants.

Comment: @Anixx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number

Comment: @Dr.user44690 what exactly in that article did you want to point?

Comment: @Anixx Just letting you know what Grassmann numbers are.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 the article does not use the notation $\bar{\theta}$. I thought it could mean complex conjugation but if $\theta$ is a generator, this makes no sense.

Comment: @Anixx $\bar{\theta}$ and $\theta^{*}$ are the same thing. Or you can think of $\bar{\theta}$ as entirely different Grassmann number.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 if $\theta$ is a generator, then $\theta^*=\theta$.

Comment: @Anixx I think he is just talking about usual Grassmann numbers. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 what do you mean? I am also talking about usual Grassmann numbers.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 if $\theta$ is just any Grassmann number, then if $\theta$ is not a zero divisor, $1/\theta$ is not undefined. And $\frac{1}{1-\theta}=1+\theta$ also does not hold. If $\theta$ is generator, then $\theta^*=\theta$ and it also does not make sense.

Comment: @Anixx I am sorry. You lost me. You are just attaching to much terminology to a very simple question.

Answer (score 1):

I think for grassmann variables the inverse is simply a derivative. Maybe you can define the operator $$\Theta = \overset{\rightarrow}{\partial}_{\theta}+\overset{\leftarrow}{\partial}_{\theta}$$
This is an inverse to your Grassmann number as you can see $\Theta.\theta = \theta.\Theta = 1$